# Adding ArrayList to ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist, streamreader

I'm trying to have nested ArrayLists, and tried to add a new ArrayList as an element of an existing one, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code:

```
    private void readDataFile()
    {
        // Open stream reader
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataFileLoc);

        string line = string.Empty;
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        myArgus.Add(new ArrayList().Add(line));

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // TODO
        }

        // Close the reader
        reader.Close();
    }
```

If I add a breakpoint and look at the data in `myArgus` (the already existing ArrayList), the first element is just `0`. It should be an ArrayList which has the first element as `10016` (that's the first line of the text file).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Edit: It's worth noting that we are required to use an ArrayList.

Comment: you should really strongly type your lists with `List<T>`.

Comment: Have you tried `List<string> myArgus = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(path));` ?

Comment: Just curiosity: Why are you *required* to use an ArrayList?

Comment: Or `ArrayList myArgus = new ArrayList(); myArgus.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ArrayList.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add.aspx) does not return ArrayList, but simply int.

So you want to add elements in 2 steps.

```
int index = myArgus.Add(new ArrayList());
((ArrayList)myArgus[index]).Add(line);
```

Note: Use strongly typed collections (`List<string>`) to avoid this type of errors.

Comment: I get an error with that code, about the object having no definition for the method `Add`. We can't use strongly typed collections for this, it has to be an ArrayList as defined like so: `ArrayList myArgus = new ArrayList();`

Comment: Alternatively, you could make myArgus a List<ArrayList> so that it "knows" what's in there, if all you plan to have inside myArgus is ArrayLists.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
myArgus.Add(new ArrayList().Add(line));
```

adds `0` as the first element to `myArgus`. Why? Because the return value of [ArrayList.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add.aspx) is defined as follows:

> **Return Value**
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The ArrayList index at which the value has been added.

Since your `new ArrayList()` does not contain any items, `line` is added at index `0`.

What you probably meant to write was:

```
var subList = new ArrayList();
subList.Add(line);
myArgus.Add(subList);
```

---

In fact, what you *should* do is to use *typed* lists:

```
List<List<string>> myArgus;
```

This helps catch this kind of error, because the compiler complains if an `int` is added instead of the expected `List<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can technically still do it in one step

```
myArgus.Add(new ArrayList() { line } );
```